# Button without style windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, button, styles

I have a problem with my button, I have seen this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jySYq5QJZes&t=174s

And he put a flat button. I do the same like him and I have this button (with an ugly windows style :( )

[image]

This is my xaml code of the button :

`<Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" Height="31" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>`

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What OS (Windows) are you on? The controls look different on Windows 7 compared to Windows 8+.

Comment: I am on Windows 7. Thank you :) @mm8

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the Button's OverrideDefaultStyle property to True.

```
<Button Content="X" OverrideDefaultStyle="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"...
```

If that doesn't work, you can redefine the template for the Button to suit your needs. Here is a very simple one:

```
<Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left"...>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PressedBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PressedBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```